# What does this symbol mean in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have an error on a property I can't access in IntelliSense but I can see it in the watch. However, it has the following symbol :`

[image]

Does anyone knows what this mean ?

Thanks you

Comment: Try to get a big screen shot. A thing without context is of no information at all.

Comment: Search for that property on that type in the object browser, it'll tell you the signature and therefore why you can't access it via code.